# где находится бд андроид приложения?

Tags: android

Сделал приложение, подключил бд, теперь когда через android studio запускаю в дебаг режиме приложение, то выскакивает предупреждение, что нужно удалить старое приложение, и все данные которые в бд удалятся.

видел в интернете что файлы должны лежать по пути `/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>`
но у меня в этой папке ничего нет, то есть папка пустая, а данные есть.

Где еще могут лежать файлы бд?

Comment: полазь по дате или просто удали старое приложение и установи новое в дебаг режиме
бг станет на него

Comment: Может вы как-то по особенному подключили какую-то особенную БД? Так то она должна лежать по тому пути, что вы указали. А удаление приложения скорее всего требуется из-за несовпадения подписей APK. Наверное, вы с разных компов ставите DEBUG версию.